# как сделать из python файла ехе файл

Tags: python

Недавно я начал писать сайт. На этом сайте я сделал кнопку для скачивания файла с программой. Но формат файла .pyw и из за того что не у всех людей установлен python (а также некоторые библиотеки) файл попросту не запуститься. Тогда я начал искать как python файл превратить в exe , но ничего не нашёл.

Можете подсказать как это сделать?                 (у меня питон версии 3.4)

Comment: Ничего не нашел? Плохо искал. Даже на этом сайте достаточно информации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы сгенерировать `.exe` файл вы можете использовать `pyinstaller`:

`pyinstaller -F -w -i "path to .ico" main.py`

`-w` заблокирует создание консольного окна, если оно вам не надо

`-F` просто уберет ненужные файлы в директории с приложением

`-i` позволит указать путь к файлу `.ico` для иконки приложения

Comment: я проверил, но к сожалению pyinstaller на моей версии python не работает.

Comment: Это плохой совет - использовать pyinstaller. Тем более без отсылки к необходимости писать свой spec файл. Правильный совет - забыть об exe, который создает pyinstaller (самораспаковывающийся в TEMP архив) и использовать Embedded Python и бесплатные инсталляторы для windows.

Answer (score 0):

Просто посмотрите это видео и сделайте как там:
https://youtu.be/CgCJwDjm_Cw

Comment: Ссылка - это хорошо, но основные моменты из нее лучше перенести в текст ответа (на случай, если со ссылкой что-то случится, и чтобы сэкономить людям время). См. [Как написать хороший ответ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)